# How to call a method from another method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call a method outwith onCreate inside of the onCreate thread. It however says the method cannot be resolved. I know the method cannot be inside of the onCreate thread so how do you call a method from it. Here is my code for the class.

```
package com.alarm.mobilegame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class startGames extends MainActivity {

public void additionCalc() {
    int Min = 1;
    int Max = 99;
    int a = Min + (int)Math.random()*(Max-Min);
    int b = Min + (int)Math.random()*(Max-Min);
    int c = (int) a + b;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_game1);

    Button buttonMathStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonMathStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView addquestion;
            TextView subquestion;
            TextView divquestion;
            TextView mulquestion;
            addition.calc();
            addquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            addquestion.setText("" + a, b);
            subquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            subquestion.setText("sub");
            divquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            divquestion.setText("div");
            mulquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            mulquestion.setText("mul");
        }});
}
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't  addition.calc() be  additionCalc() ?

Comment: @Andrew Stewart, Gautham is correct.

Comment: What is going on with your code? Lol what is `addquestion.setText("" + a, b);`?

Comment: Andrew, I think you want the `setText()` that only takes one `param` which I believe is what @mikeyaworski is saying. Not this one http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView.BufferType)

Comment: It would be great if you also read and follow some guidelines about Naming Conventions. (For example, Class names should be nouns in UpperCamelCase, with the first letter of every word capitalized.) Source: Internet.

Comment: @codemagic I'd be surprised if he even knew that what he was doing was passing it two parameters. I would guess he's trying to add them or something.

Comment: @mikeyaworski hmmm...that's possible, not really sure what's going on

Comment: What's your goal here, Andrew? I'm very confused by ALL of your code. The simple answer to your question is `additioncalc();` instead of `addition.calc()`, although your code still wouldn't compile and still wouldn't make sense. You need to start replying to us so that we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call on a method from onCreate like this:

Example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example);
    myMethod(); //Any parameters you need in the method can be passed through the parentheses
}

myMethod(){
//Do stuff in here
}
```

In your case, you should put this line in your onCreate() to call the method:

```
additionCalc();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems - the first one being that you are not calling the method you created properly.

1. Change `addition.calc();` `to additionCalc();`
2. Calling that method will do *nothing* for you. It will add the numbers in that method, but the variables are local to that method, so nothing will happen in `onCreate`.
3. To make `additionCalc()` useful, have it `return` the addition calculation. For example:

   ```
   public int additionCalc() { // not void anymore - it returns an int
       int Min = 1;
       int Max = 99;
       int a = Min + (int)Math.random()*(Max-Min);
       int b = Min + (int)Math.random()*(Max-Min);
       int c = (int) a + b;
       return c; // return the sum
   }
   ```
4. To use the method, instead of `addquestion.setText("" + a, b);` you can use
   `addquestion.setText("" + additionCalc());` and it will set the text to be the sum.
5. If you want to use `a` and/or `b` in your `onCreate` method, then you have to declare them in that method.